# overflow:hidden does not work on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, overflow

```css
    #nav_bar {  position: relative; height: 100%; overflow:hidden; width: 21%;  }
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
      <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I have the above structure in my .html page. I want to add `overflow:hidden;` property to `#nav_bar`. It works great on chrome but firefox behaves like there no `overflow: hidden` property and adds a *scrollbar* into the page. Is there something thatI don't know about Firefox?

Comment: post your CSS and possibly a jsfiddle showing the behavior.

Comment: your code is working. maybe the scroll bar added by firefox is for other element in your page.

Answer (score 0):

user `overflow`

```css
#nav_bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 21%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    ... ... ...
  </ul>
</div>
```